# Facing Issue With Django Machina Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-settings

I am Working on Rating Professor Website Using `Django Framework`.So That's Why I am Using `Machina` Forum But Facing `Templates` Issue In `Settings` .Loaders Are Not Working  `'APP_DIRS': True,` But When I Change  `'APP_DIRS': False` ,And Add `MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR` To Templates Directory Machina Website Forum Works Fine But My Actual Website Goes Off Because of **No Templates Exits Error**.

Question is That Can i Use Both Machina And My Template Directory at Same time And how ?
If I add Machina Templates to `Pycharm` Project Templates and Make them as Templates then it's Work Or not ?
**There is Only Issue With Machina Templates Everything is Working Excellent . I Just Wanted Both Templates to Work On My Website .**
**Setting.py**

```
import os
from machina import MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from machina import MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djangoproject.apps.DjangoprojectConfig',
    'axes',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'pinax.comments',
    'sslserver',
    'simple_history',
    'admin_honeypot',
    'captcha',
# Machina dependencies:
    'mptt',
    'haystack',


    # Machina apps:
    'machina',
    'machina.apps.forum',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_attachments',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_polls',
    'machina.apps.forum_feeds',
    'machina.apps.forum_moderation',
    'machina.apps.forum_search',
    'machina.apps.forum_tracking',
    'machina.apps.forum_member',
    'machina.apps.forum_permission',







]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # AxesBackend should be the first backend in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list.
    'axes.backends.AxesBackend',

    # Django ModelBackend is the default authentication backend.
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
    'machina.apps.forum_permission.middleware.ForumPermissionMiddleware',





]

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['axes.W003']

ROOT_URLCONF = 'review.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djangoproject/../templates')],
         'APP_DIRS': True,


        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'machina.core.context_processors.metadata',

            ],
        },
    },
]
CACHES = {
'default': {
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
},
'machina_attachments': {
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
'LOCATION': '/tmp',
}
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'review.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR,

]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # ...
    MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR,
)
MACHINA_DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATED_USER_FORUM_PERMISSIONS = [
    'can_see_forum',
    'can_read_forum',
    'can_start_new_topics',
    'can_reply_to_topics',
    'can_edit_own_posts',
    'can_post_without_approval',
    'can_create_polls',
    'can_vote_in_polls',
    'can_download_file',
]
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (


    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, r'C:\Users\Windows 10\PycharmProjects\review\templates\djangoproject'),
)


PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
AXES_ENABLED = False

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='blog-home'
LOGIN_URL='login'


MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880"

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'SECRET'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'SECRET'
```